# Imported an eclipse project into android studio and trying to fix library problems

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle

This is the kind of error I get:

```
Error:(8) No resource identifier found for attribute 'plaColumnNumber' in package 'com.dmb.recipeapp'
```

This is my Gradle file:

[image: screenshot of gradle file]

Comment: I need help anyone already fixed tihs error ?

Comment: Kindly post your gradle code as formatted text, not as image, so that we can better read and copy&paste.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work  ,this is my first post, I'll try again !